# Why is the for loop returning NA vectors in some positions (in R)?

Tags: r, for-loop

Following a youtube tutorial, I have created a vector x [-3,6,2,5,9].
Then I create an empty variable of length 5 with the function 'numeric(5)'

I want to store the squares of my vector x in 'Storage2' with a for loop.
When I do the for loop and update my variable, it returns a very strange thing:
[1]  9  4  0  9 25 36 NA NA 81

I can see all numbers in x have been squared, but the order is so random, and there's more than 5.

Also, why are there NAs?? If it's because the last number of x is 9 (and so this number defines the length??), and there's no 7 and 8 position, I would understand, but then I'm also missing positions 1, 3 and 4, so there should be more NAs...

I'm just starting with R, so please keep it simple, and correct me if I'm wrong during my thought process! Thank you!!

```
x <- c(-3,6,2,5,9)

Storage2 <- numeric(5)

for(i in x){
  Storage2[i] <- i^2
}

Storage2
# [1]  9  4  0  9 25 36 NA NA 81
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over the elements of `x` not over the positions as probably intended. You need to change your loop like so:

```
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  Storage2[i] <- x[i]^2
}

Storage2
# [1]  9 36  4 25 81
```

(*Note:* `1:length(x)` can also be expressed as `seq_along(x)`, as pointed out by *@NelsonGon* in comments and might be faster.)

However, R is a vectorized language so you can simply do that:

```
Storage2 <- x^2
Storage2
# [1]  9 36  4 25 81
```

Comment: Yeah that works thanks! (I know I can do it simply but I am just trying out loops)

I was mainly trying to understand why it gave me that result... So you always have to specify the positions right? (i in 1:vector)

Comment: @Sergi It's fine doing `for(i in x){print(i^2)}`, but it's related to the indices of `Storage2[i]`, since the `i`s resulting in `c(-3,6,2,5,9)` not in `x(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` as you've probably expected.